# Input elements within popup window do not respond to user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a pop up window with two input elements that do not respond to user input. In the past, I've had input elements with a very similar setup that respond to user input just fine. I'm not sure if this is caused by there being a delay with the asynchronous nature of useState or if I have overlooked something with my setup trying to make this pop up window. I appreciate you're time and help. Thank you!

Update: I have made a mock input element outside of the pop up window using the same set up for the Onchange and the value properties and it responds to user input. This makes me believe that useState is not the issue here.

Definition:

```
 function Popup({ onClose, onSave }) {
    const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState("");
    const [focus, setFocus] = useState("");

    function handleFrequencyChange(event) {
      setFrequency(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleFocusChange(event) {
      setFocus(event.target.value);
    }
    return (
          <h3>Journal Goals</h3>
          <label style={{ display: "block", marginBottom: "10px" }}>
            Frequency:
            <input type="text" style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }} onChange={handleFrequencyChange}
             value={frequency}
            />
          </label>
          <label style={{ display: "block", marginBottom: "10px", marginLeft: "32px" }}>
            Focus:
            <input type="text" style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }} onChange={handleFocusChange} value={focus} />
          </label>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
            <button
              onMouseEnter={adjacentHandleMouseEnter}
              onMouseLeave={adjacentHandleMouseLeave}
             onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
            <button
              onMouseEnter={adjacentHandleMouseEnter2}
              onMouseLeave={adjacentHandleMouseLeave2}
              onClick={closePopup}>Cancel</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  function openPopup() {
    setShowPopup(true);
  }

  function closePopup() {
    setShowPopup(false);
  }

  function handleSave(data) {
    console.log(data);
    closePopup();
  }
```

Utilization:

```
 <button
          onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
          onClick={openPopup}>Goals</button>
   {showPopup && (
          <Popup onClose={closePopup} onSave={handleSave} />
        )}
```

handleSave --- console.log(data):
SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onClick', _targetInst: null, type: 'click', nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: button, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue after making changes to Popup's props and getting rid of the openPopup function to instead use an arrow function that directly calls setOpenPopup(true). Below are the changes that I made.

```
From:  onClick={openPopup}

  To: onClick={() => {
          setOpenPopup(true)


From:   {showPopup && (
          <Popup onClose={closePopup} onSave={handleSave} />
        )}
To:  {showPopup && <Popup onClose={setOpenPopup} />}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i see you didnt export the popup function.

```
function Popup({ onClose, onSave }) {...}
```

and also i am not sure but why is your code

```
const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  function openPopup() {
    setShowPopup(true);
  }

  function closePopup() {
    setShowPopup(false);
  }

  function handleSave(data) {
    console.log(data);
    closePopup();
  }
```

at the bottom
it may causes the problems

Comment: Thank you for your response! All the code exist within one file so no need to export the function. It should be within scope. What specifically might cause problems at the bottom?

Comment: i see, could you then by any chanse show me the full view of the file? Github, codesandebox